Change from OLE DB to ODBC connection both connected to SQL Server?
I have an Excel file that was originally created with connection type being an OLE DB Query. This oledb connects to a SQL Server database and executes a stored procedure dbo.usp_GetEmployees which returns columns EmpId, FName, LName.
I created an ODBC connection that also connects to a SQL Server database, and run the query select EmpId, FName, LName from Employee. Both odbc and oledb connection return the same exact thing, the only difference being that one runs a select statement while the other runs a stored procedure.
When I change the Excel connection to the odbc, I get an error

You cannot choose a connection file that is incompatible with the existing connection

Is there a way around this?
